# XmlWriter outputs unexpected encoding when printing to console

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

While learning the C# `XmlWriter` class I came across some strange behavior. When outputting to a file it uses UTF-8 as expected but when outputting to the Console it uses my system code-page (862) instead of UTF-8. I know consoles don't support UTF-8, so I'm wondering if `XmlWriter` defaults to system code-page if the stream is a console?

Code to reproduce behavior:

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlwriterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true
            };

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("users");

                writer.WriteStartElement("user");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("age", "42");
                writer.WriteString("John Doe");
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("user");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("age", "39");
                writer.WriteString("Jane Doe");

                writer.WriteEndDocument();
                writer.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Actual output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Codepage - 862"?>`

**edit**
My question is not how to achieve the expected output in the console. It is **why** this happens in the first place

Comment: how about creating a custom `StringWriter` that use `StringBuilder` by overriding `Encoding` property to `UTF8` and output in the console this string builder that represent the xml.

Comment: Use a MemoryStream as the Stream output: it doesn't get in the way. If you use a StringWriter, the encoding will be always UTF-16, no matter what you specify as the `XmlWriterSettings.Encoding` property value (which should be `Encoding = Encoding.UTF8` or `new UTF8Encoding(false)` if you want to make sure there's no BOM in the output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update as per comment**

*Why this happens in the first place* : because the default `Encoding` for `Console.Out` is not `UTF-8`, I'm doing a test like this:

1.1 - Default `Encoding` :

```
TextWriter textWriter = Console.Out;

Console.WriteLine(textWriter.Encoding.BodyName);
```

1.2 - Result :

```
ibm850
```

2.1 - Custom `Encoding` of `Console.Out` :

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
TextWriter textWriter = Console.Out;

Console.WriteLine(textWriter.Encoding.BodyName);
```

2.2 - Result :

```
utf-8
```

The whole code :

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true
};

Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("users");

    writer.WriteStartElement("user");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("age", "42");
    writer.WriteString("John Doe");
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement("user");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("age", "39");
    writer.WriteString("Jane Doe");

    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Close();

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <user age="42">John Doe</user>
  <user age="39">Jane Doe</user>
</users>
```

**Old code**

You can create a custom `StringWriter` by using `StringBuilder` and *override* `Encoding` property like :

1 - Custom class:

```
public class EncodedStringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public EncodedStringWriter(StringBuilder sb, Encoding encoding)
        : base(sb)
    {
        _Encoding = encoding;
    }

    private readonly Encoding _Encoding;

    public override Encoding Encoding => _Encoding;
}
```

2 - Construct the XML, by using the *custom stringWriter* :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
EncodedStringWriter stringWriter = new EncodedStringWriter(sb, Encoding.UTF8);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true
};

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("users");

    writer.WriteStartElement("user");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("age", "42");
    writer.WriteString("John Doe");
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement("user");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("age", "39");
    writer.WriteString("Jane Doe");

    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <user age="42">John Doe</user>
  <user age="39">Jane Doe</user>
</users>
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I think you misunderstood my question I edited it for clarification

Comment: @medic17 you're welcome,  i'm adding some explanation, i hope you find this helpful.